# How can I create a segue after a certain amount of seconds between view controllers without any buttons or swipe gestures?

Tags: swift, xcode

At the entrance of my main storyboard, I have a loader animation from the Lottie library, after a few seconds I want the app to animate to another view controller which is my home page, How do I do this? I would prefer to not use a button or swipe gesture to have to go from the loader to the home page, but would I have do use the Timer class in some way, or would I need to create a segue using storyboard?

I already attempted using other questions similar to this on Stack Overflow, but I continuously get errors about performSegue() not having an identifier

Comment: Have you actually given the segue an identifiers?

Comment: Late comment, you may already have been given a solution. (First? Why haven't you given more details? By SO standards, things are rather vague.) My question? (Keep in mind, you really have asked a vague question with no code or detail.) You state that *"At the entrance of my main storyboard, I have a loader animation from the Lottie library"*. So you are using a third party library? More, are you trying to do something in your **Launch.storyboard** that simply cannot be done?  Remember, a launch storyboard **is not** a view controller you have control of.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways: `Segue` or `present(_ viewController:UIViewController, animated:Bool, completion: () -> Void)`

So, in your 1st ViewController `viewDidLoad` method you can implement a `Timer`. Such as, `Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: TimeInterval, repeats: Bool, block: (Timer) -> Void)` and set a time, set repeat to false and then the block, you can do whatever you want, such as present a new view controller. Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    Timer.scheduledTime(withTimeInterval: 10.0, repeats: false) { (timer) in
        self.present(ViewController2(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```